# How can I perform the join among 7 tables (2 very large,1medium and 4small tables) efficiently in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have 7 iceberg tables and I'm reading them as dataframe in databricks using the below code

```
`df1 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 250million
`df2 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 250million
`df3 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 2million
`df4 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 7
`df5 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 11
`df6 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 27
`df7 = spark.read.format('iceberg').load(path1)` #row count 31
```

I need to perform left join on df1 with the other 6 dataframes. I have written the code below, but it's taking a lot of time to execute it. Is there any efficient method to do this?

I know I can broadcast the small tables and perform the join, but my question is how to efficiently join the very large and medium tables.

```
broadcast_df4 = broadcast(df4)
broadcast_df5 = broadcast(df5)
broadcast_df6 = broadcast(df6)
broadcast_df7 = broadcast(df7)

joined_df = df1.join(broadcast_df4,id4,left)
               .select(df1.col1,broadcast_df4.col2,broadcast_df4.col3)
               .join(broadcast_df5,roll,left)
               .select(broadcast_df5.name)
               .....
               .....
               <similar for other broadcasted table>
               .join(df2,df1.acc = df2.key,left).select(df2.col5,df2.col6...)
               .join(df3,df1.c_id = df3.a_id,left).select(df3.col9,df3.col10...)
joined_df.count()
```

My above code is taking a huge time, almost 1+ hour to run and multiple jobs are created, and few of the jobs running for a longer time. can this be done in better and faster way? Also does using spark.sql helps on this?

Comment: You'll need to understad the spark query exection plan to start optimising. I suggest you post the plan. Or you could just brute force it and increase the compute and or nodes

Comment: ... or you could abandon relational db tenets and denormalize your large tables ahead of time.

Comment: Please add the output of resultDf.explain() to your question, where resultDf is the result dataframe of all joins